# BroadcastCopyBlock for TPL Dataflow with guaranteed delivery

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, broadcast, tpl-dataflow

I would be glad for some input on the following implementation of a `BroadcastCopyBlock` in TPL Dataflow, which copies a received message to all consumers, that registered to the `BroadcastCopyBlock` and guarantees delivery to all consumers, which are linked to the block at the time it receives the message. (Unlike the `BroadcastBlock` which does not guarntee delivery of messages, if the next one comes in, before the former message has been delivered to all consumers).

My main concern is the reserving of messages and releasing of reservations. What would happen, if a receiving block decides to not handle the message? My understanding is, this would create a memory leak, since the message would be kept indefinitely. I'm thinking, that I should somehow mark the message as unused, but I'm not sure, how. I was thinking about some artificial message sink (an `ActionBlock` with no action), or can I just mark a message as discarded?

Further Input on the implementation is also appreciated.

This is probably almost a duplicate of the following question, but I would prefer to use my own class, instead of a method to create the block. Or would that be considered bad style?
[BroadcastBlock with Guaranteed Delivery in TPL Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127660/broadcastblock-with-guaranteed-delivery-in-tpl-dataflow)

```
/// <summary>
/// Broadcasts the same message to multiple consumers. This does NOT clone the message, all consumers receive an identical message
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class BrodcastCopyBlock<T> : IPropagatorBlock<T, T>
{
    private ITargetBlock<T> In { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds a TransformBlock for each target, that subscribed to this block
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IDictionary<ITargetBlock<T>, TransformBlock<T, T>> _OutBlocks = new Dictionary<ITargetBlock<T>, TransformBlock<T, T>>();


    public BrodcastCopyBlock()
    {
        In = new ActionBlock<T>(message => Process(message));

        In.Completion.ContinueWith(task =>
                                   {
                                       if (task.Exception == null)
                                           Complete();
                                       else
                                           Fault(task.Exception);
                                   }
          );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a transform source block for the passed target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target"></param>
    private void CreateOutBlock(ITargetBlock<T> target)
    {
        if (_OutBlocks.ContainsKey(target))
            return;

        var outBlock = new TransformBlock<T, T>(e => e);
        _OutBlocks[target] = outBlock;
    }

    private void Process(T message)
    {
        foreach (var outBlock in _OutBlocks.Values)
        {
            outBlock.Post(message);
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, T messageValue, ISourceBlock<T> source, bool consumeToAccept)
    {
        return In.OfferMessage(messageHeader, messageValue, source, consumeToAccept);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Complete()
    {
        foreach (var outBlock in _OutBlocks.Values)
        {
            ((ISourceBlock<T>)outBlock).Complete();
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Fault(Exception exception)
    {
        foreach (var outBlock in _OutBlocks.Values)
        {
            ((ISourceBlock<T>)outBlock).Fault(exception);
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task Completion => Task.WhenAll(_OutBlocks.Select(b => b.Value.Completion));

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<T> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
    {
        CreateOutBlock(target);
        return _OutBlocks[target].LinkTo(target, linkOptions);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public T ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<T> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        return ((ISourceBlock<T>)_OutBlocks[target]).ConsumeMessage(messageHeader, target, out messageConsumed);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<T> target)
    {
        return ((ISourceBlock<T>)_OutBlocks[target]).ReserveMessage(messageHeader, target);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<T> target)
    {
        ((ISourceBlock<T>)_OutBlocks[target]).ReleaseReservation(messageHeader, target);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from `BroadcastBlock`?

Comment: @svick BroadcastBlock does not duplicate the Messages. The first consumer, which receives the message, deletes it from the queue

Comment: Either that, or I have completely missunderstood the concept of BroadcastBlock

Comment: That's what makes it *broadcast*, that it sends messages to all linked blocks.

Comment: yeah, but as I understand it, only one of the receivers can handle the message. As soon as one of the receivers handles the message, it's deleted from the queue?`

Comment: OK, I'm really confused right now, I must have checked out a weird tutorial or something... But the default `BroadcastBlock` actually still doesn't work for me, since I need guaranteed delivery off the messages, which as it seems, is not guaranteed by the `BroadcastBlock`. I'm gonna reformulate the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL/DR**
Your implementation uses the [`Post`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604569.aspx) method inside the [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx), which still will lose the data if target rejects the message, switch to the [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604550.aspx) one, and, probably, you don't need to implenment all these methods, you need only [`ITargetBlock<in TInput>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604405.aspx) interface implementation.

---

I want to clarify something before coming back to your main question. I think that you are confused by some options from [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604386.aspx) library, and I want explain them a bit here. The behavior you're saying `The first consumer, which receives the message, deletes it from the queue` is not about the [`BroadcastBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604434.aspx), it is about the multiple consumers linked for an [`ISourceBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604404.aspx), like [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604455.aspx):

```
var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();
var consumer1 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => {});
var consumer2 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); });
buffer.LinkTo(consumer1);
buffer.LinkTo(consumer2);
// this one will go only for one consumer, no console output present
buffer.Post(1);
```

What the [`BroadcastBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604434.aspx) do is exactly what are you talking about, consider this code:

```
private static void UnboundedCase()
{
    var broadcast = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i);
    var fastAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"FAST Unbounded Block: {i}"));
    var slowAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine($"SLOW Unbounded Block: {i}");
        });
    broadcast.LinkTo(slowAction, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    broadcast.LinkTo(fastAction, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        broadcast.SendAsync(i);
    }
    broadcast.Complete();
    slowAction.Completion.Wait();
}
```

The output will be

```
FAST Unbounded Block: 0
FAST Unbounded Block: 1
FAST Unbounded Block: 2
SLOW Unbounded Block: 0
SLOW Unbounded Block: 1
SLOW Unbounded Block: 2
```

However, this can be done only is the speed of incoming data is less than the speed of processing the data, because in other case your memory will end up quickly because of buffers grow, as you stated in your question. Let's see what will happen if we use the [`ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604401.aspx) for limit the incoming data buffer for a slow block:

```
private static void BoundedCase()
{
    var broadcast = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i);
    var fastAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"FAST Bounded Block: {i}"));
    var slowAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine($"SLOW Bounded Block: {i}");
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 2 });
    broadcast.LinkTo(slowAction, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    broadcast.LinkTo(fastAction, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        broadcast.SendAsync(i);
    }
    broadcast.Complete();
    slowAction.Completion.Wait();
}
```

The output will be

```
FAST Bounded Block: 0
FAST Bounded Block: 1
FAST Bounded Block: 2
SLOW Bounded Block: 0
SLOW Bounded Block: 1
```

As you can see, our slow block lost the last message, which is not what we are looking for. The reason for this is that the [`BroadcastBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604434.aspx), by default, uses the [`Post`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604569.aspx) method to deliver messages. According [official Intro Document](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782):

> - Post
>
>   - An extension method that asynchronously posts to the target block. It returns immediately whether the data could be accepted or not, **and it does not allow for the target to consume the message at a later time**.
> - SendAsync
>
>   - An extension method that asynchronously sends to target blocks while supporting buffering. A `Post` operation on a target is asynchronous, but if a target wants to postpone the offered data, there is nowhere for the data to be buffered and the target must instead be forced to decline. `SendAsync` enables asynchronous posting of the data with buffering, such that **if a target postpones, it will later be able to retrieve the postponed data from the temporary buffer used for this one asynchronously posted message**.

So, this method could help us in our mission, let's introduce some wrapper [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx), which do exactly what we want - [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604550.aspx) the data for our real processors:

```
private static void BoundedWrapperInfiniteCase()
{
    var broadcast = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i);
    var fastAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"FAST Wrapper Block: {i}"));
    var slowAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"SLOW Wrapper Block: {i}");
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 2 });
    var fastActionWrapper = new ActionBlock<int>(i => fastAction.SendAsync(i));
    var slowActionWrapper = new ActionBlock<int>(i => slowAction.SendAsync(i));

    broadcast.LinkTo(slowActionWrapper, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    broadcast.LinkTo(fastActionWrapper, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        broadcast.SendAsync(i);
    }
    broadcast.Complete();
    slowAction.Completion.Wait();
}
```

The output will be

```
FAST Unbounded Block: 0
FAST Unbounded Block: 1
FAST Unbounded Block: 2
SLOW Unbounded Block: 0
SLOW Unbounded Block: 1
SLOW Unbounded Block: 2
```

**But** this waiting will never end - our basic wrapper does not propagate the completion for linked blocks, and the [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) can't be linked to anything. We can try to wait for an wrapper completion:

```
private static void BoundedWrapperFiniteCase()
{
    var broadcast = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i);
    var fastAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"FAST finite Block: {i}"));
    var slowAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine($"SLOW finite Block: {i}");
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 2 });
    var fastActionWrapper = new ActionBlock<int>(i => fastAction.SendAsync(i));
    var slowActionWrapper = new ActionBlock<int>(i => slowAction.SendAsync(i));
    broadcast.LinkTo(slowActionWrapper, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    broadcast.LinkTo(fastActionWrapper, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        broadcast.SendAsync(i);
    }
    broadcast.Complete();
    slowActionWrapper.Completion.Wait();
}
```

The output will be

```
FAST finite Block: 0
FAST finite Block: 1
FAST finite Block: 2
SLOW finite Block: 0
```

Which is definitely not what we wanted - [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) finished all the job, and the posting for a last message wouldn't be awaited for. Moreover, we don't even see the second message because we exit the method before `Sleep` method ends! So you definitely need your own implementation for this.

Now, at last, some thoughts about your code:

1. You do not need such large amount of methods being implemented - your wrapper will be used as [`ITargetBlock<in TInput>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604405.aspx), so implement only that interface.
2. Your implementation uses the [`Post`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604569.aspx) method inside the [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx), which, as we saw, could lead to data loss in case of some problems on consumer's side. Consider [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604550.aspx) method instead.
3. After previous change, you should measure up the performance of your dataflow - if you got many async waits for data to deliver, you probably will see the performance and/or memory problems. This should be fixed with some advanced settings which are discussed in [linked documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782).
4. Your implementation of the [`Completion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604637.aspx) task actually reverses the order of your dataflow - you are waiting for targets to complete, which, as I think, is not good practice - you probably should create an ending block for your dataflow (this could be even [`NullTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604559.aspx) block, which simply synchronously drops the incoming message), and wait for it to be completed.

Comment: @VMTAtm thanks for your detailed answer, you really helped me a lot. I just have a few follow up questions: Regarding 1: Why should I not implement `ISourceBlock`? after all, I want to be able to link other blocks to my `BroadcastBlock` (`broadcastBlock.LinkTo(consumerBlock)`)? Regarding 4: Can you elaborate a bit more? I would assume, my implementation waits, until all its source blocks complete and then propagates the completion event forward to its _OutBlocks (which, if propagateCompletion is set to true, forward the completion to the consuming blocks of the `BroadcastBlock`)

Comment: 1. From the code you've provided that was not obvious for me, but if such behavior is intended, than you should implement that. 2. In your code you provide the `Completion` task as the task, which waits all of your `outputs` to complete, not the sources, if some code is attached to this task, it will execute only after your `outputs` are done, which can be unexpected.

Comment: 1. OK, 2. I'm a bit confused now. The `In`-Block is the Target of my `BroadcastBlock`, so it's the block which will be subcribed to, if somebody calls `sourceblock.LinkTo(myBroadcastBlock)` (See also the 'LinkTo' method in my implementation). I may have a missunderstanding, but it seems to me, that I am awaiting Completion of my previous blocks, and then complete the `BroadcastBlock` itself?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now. You're talking about the `Completion` Event of the Task itself. That's totally wrong of course

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add to [VMAtm's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639607/68955) that in `BoundedWrapperInfiniteCase`, you can manually propagate the completion. Add the following lines before the call to `broadcast.SendAsync()` then wait for both actions to complete to make the action wrappers complete the inner actions:

```
slowActionWrapper.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted) ((IDataflowBlock)slowAction).Fault(t.Exception);
        else slowAction.Complete();
    });
fastActionWrapper.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted) ((IDataflowBlock)fastAction).Fault(t.Exception);
        else fastAction.Complete();
    });
```

e.g.

```
var broadcast = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i);
var fastAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"FAST Wrapper Block: {i}"));
var slowAction = new ActionBlock<int>(i =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"SLOW Wrapper Block: {i}");
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 2 });
var fastActionWrapper = new ActionBlock<int>(i => fastAction.SendAsync(i));
var slowActionWrapper = new ActionBlock<int>(i => slowAction.SendAsync(i));

broadcast.LinkTo(slowActionWrapper, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
broadcast.LinkTo(fastActionWrapper, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

// Manually propagate completion to the inner actions
slowActionWrapper.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted) ((IDataflowBlock)slowAction).Fault(t.Exception);
        else slowAction.Complete();
    });
fastActionWrapper.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted) ((IDataflowBlock)fastAction).Fault(t.Exception);
        else fastAction.Complete();
    });

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    broadcast.SendAsync(i);
broadcast.Complete();

// Wait for both inner actions to complete
Task.WaitAll(slowAction.Completion, fastAction.Completion);
```

The output will be the same as in VMAtm's answer, but all tasks will properly complete.